# Installed tmux 2.9 and now SSH script it throwing an error. protocol version mismatch (client 7, server 8)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, script, tmux

I now get this error with tmux 2.9 where with tmux 2.7 it had no issues.

```
[15:02:59] nod @ server01: ~ $>  ssh-multi2_1.sh server10 server11

usage: new-window [-adkP] [-c start-directory] [-F format] [-n window-name] [-t target-window] [command]

protocol version mismatch (client 7, server 8)

protocol version mismatch (client 7, server 8)

protocol version mismatch (client 7, server 8)

protocol version mismatch (client 7, server 8)

[15:07:49] nod @ server01: ~ $>
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# ssh-multi
# D.Kovalov
# Based on http://linuxpixies.blogspot.jp/2011/06/tmux-copy-mode-and-how-to-control.html

# a script to ssh multiple servers over multiple tmux panes
# TMUX 2.1+
# ./ssh-multi.sh server{01..16}

starttmux() {
    if [ -z "$HOSTS" ]; then
      echo -n "Please provide of list of hosts separated by spaces [ENTER]: "
       read HOSTS
    fi

    local hosts=( $HOSTS )
    local target="ssh-multi ${host[0]}"


    tmux new-window -n "${target}" ssh ${hosts[0]}
    unset hosts[0];
    for i in "${hosts[@]}"; do
        tmux split-window -t :"${target}" -h  "ssh $i"
        tmux select-layout -t :"${target}" tiled > /dev/null
    done
    tmux select-pane -t 0
    tmux set-window-option -t :"${target}"  synchronize-panes on > /dev/null

}

HOSTS=${HOSTS:=$*}

starttmux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocol version 7 was last used in tmux 1.8, it has been 8 ever since. So my guess is you are not running the tmux binary you are expecting to run.

Comment: Use `hash -t tmux` to find out where bash is searching for your tmux. Use `hash -d tmux` to make it forget the old location; and use `which tmux` to see what the "new" location will be.